How can I increase the quality of a matplotlib image (jpg) which is inserted into a MS Word document table?
I am writing a Python program to automatically create a variety of math and science worksheets. The program must generate new problems each time it runs with the input of only a few parameters, such as how many questions. Below is a pilot program which provides the student with a polygon which must be reflected in some manner.
I have a main Python module which creates a Word document with a table and then calls another module which creates and returns a simple cartesian plot of a polygon. The main module inserts the plot into a cell in the table and then loops to do it again. This is the main module:
import os
import random
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from datetime import datetime
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement, ns
import Trapezoid_in_Cartesian_Grid_1
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

doc = Document()

tbl = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=0)
tbl.add_column(width=Inches(0.4))
tbl.add_column(width=Inches(3.0))
tbl.add_column(width=Inches(3.0))


def image_to_jpg(image_path):
    path = Path(image_path)
    if path.suffix not in {'.jpg', '.png', '.jfif', '.exif', '.gif',    '.tiff', '.bmp'}:
        jpg_image_path = f'{path.parent / path.stem}_result.png'
        Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB').save(jpg_image_path, quality = 95)
        return jpg_image_path
    return image_path


for i in range(10):
    a = random.randint(-8,8)
    b = random.randint(-8,8)
    h = random.randint(-3,3)
    k = random.randint(-3,3)
    path = Trapezoid_in_Cartesian_Grid_1.ReflectTrap01OverXaxis(a,b,h,k)
    image_path = image_to_jpg(path)
    
    row = tbl.add_row()
    cell1 = tbl.cell(i,0)
    cell1.text = str(i+1) + "."
    cell2 = tbl.cell(i,1) 
    cell2.text = "Reflect the figure over the y-axis."
    cell3 = tbl.cell(i,2)
    paragraph = tbl.rows[i].cells[2].paragraphs[0]
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    run.add_picture(image_path)
   
# get current date and time and convert to string
current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
print("Current date & time : ", current_datetime)
str_current_datetime = str(current_datetime)
 
# create a file object along with extension
file_name = "WS_Proj " + str_current_datetime
header = doc.sections[0].header
header.paragraphs[0].text = file_name

doc.save(file_name + ".docx")

The module, function ReflectTrap01OverXaxis, which is called is:
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from docx.shared import Inches
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import random

a = random.randint(-8,8)
b = random.randint(-8,8)
h = random.randint(3,6)
k = random.randint(3,6)

current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
str_current_datetime = str(current_datetime)


def ReflectTrap01OverXaxis(a,b,h,k):
       
   #Creates a polygon with certain vertices (verts1)
    verts1 = [(a,b),(a+h,b),(a+h,b-k),(a,b-k+1),(a,b)]
    codes1 = [Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.CLOSEPOLY]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2.5,2.5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    path1 = Path(verts1, codes1)
    patch1 = patches.PathPatch(path1, edgecolor = "black", facecolor = "None", lw=0.8, zorder = 3)
    ax.add_patch(patch1)
    
   #Sets x and y axes
    ax.set_xlim(-12,12)
    ax.set_ylim(-12,12)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.tick_params(labelsize = 6)
    plt.xlabel(None, fontsize = 9)
   #Determines the size of the plot
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [3,3]
    
    
    plt.axhline(color = "black")
    plt.axvline(color = "black")
    
    ax.grid(which = "both",color = "black", linewidth=0.5)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    
   #Creates a unique file name with date and time
    current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
    str_current_datetime = str(current_datetime)
    file_name = "fig1 " + str_current_datetime
    plt.savefig(file_name, format = "png")
    
    return file_name

The quality of the jpg inserted into the table is too low. I've researched here and elsewhere and I've tried different image file formats such as svg and pdf. I've also tried changing the dpi. When I increase the dpi the quality goes up but the image size does also and the image must fit in a table column which is 3 inches wide. Here is a screen cap of the Word document and the low quality image.Thanks in advance.


maybe keep it as png instead of converting to jpg. OR maybe you have to generate image with bigger size (figsize)

It seems that add_picture takes the width keyword, so you could increase the dpi but force the width to 3 inches.

@RuthC Thank you for your response. I added "width = 3.0" first and then "width = 2.8" (NO quotation marks) as a kwarg in add_picture and NOW the image doesn't appear at all. Only the text.

If your target is MS Word and your data is in spreadsheet form (see lower left). Then it is fairly simple to embed the data as vectors direct in the page via "charting". Advantages are you can have selectable series for different views, such as a question and an answer. Thus only need programming to switch on and off and for export to PDF.
Depending on skill (spot the error, when I saved the below screenshot, I was initially reflecting values about the wrong axis). You should better that, so your quality cannot be surpassed.



thank you. Excel does indeed produce a beautiful graph. I am trying to automate the production of these worksheets to sell to teachers and parents, hence, Python. There is a lot I can do with Word and Excel, manually. I started with VBA and Python In Excel. It's all a matter of efficiency and best fit. I would give your answer an up vote if I had the required reputation. Thanks.
